# When checking out a svn repository by date, does the date request propagate to external repositories?

Tags: svn

If you have a repository with several external repositories pointed to with svn:externals, and you do a svn checkout with the --revision specified as a date, will it also retrieve the older revisions of the external repositories, or it will just checkout the head of the external repositories?

For example:

```
svn checkout https://www.example.com/svn/myproject --revision {"2010-07-01 12:00"}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure. You may refer to [Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, svn checks out the revision specified in the externals directive, or the head of the referenced url if there is no revision specified.